# Protractor - How to submit a form in firefox (works ok in chrome)

Tags: firefox, protractor

In Chrome

```
input.sendKeys('123\n');
```

submits the form and sends me to the result page, as does

```
input.sendKeys('123');
input.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER); // or .RETURN
```

but in firefox, neither approach work, I can't seem to get <kbd>enter</kbd> to work that way and so I stay on the same (original) page and the test fails.

I keep getting (Firefox only):

#### Failed: Element `<input class="gNO89b" name="btnK" type="submit">` could not be scrolled into view

I've also tried:

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();  //invalid (older?) syntax.
```

also

```
input.sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
input.sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
input.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
```

also, suing the submit button on the page

```
$('input[value="Google Search"]').click();
```

also

```
$('input[name="btnK"]').click();
```

also

```
input.sendKeys('123');
input.sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
$('input[value="Google Search"][name="btnK"]').click();
```

They mostly work in chrome, just not in firefox, or at worst, in neither.

The failure (showing I am still on the original page) is

```
[firefox #01] Failures:                                                                                                                   
[firefox #01] 1) Google search field should have a result page                                                                            
[firefox #01]   Message:                                                                                                                  
[firefox #01]     Expected 'About Store                                                                                                   
[firefox #01]     Gmail                                                                                                                   
[firefox #01]     Images                                                                                                                  
[firefox #01]     Sign in                                                                                                                 
[firefox #01]     PrivacyTermsSettings                                                                                                    
[firefox #01]     AdvertisingBusiness How Search works' to contain '123'.                                                                 
[firefox #01]   Stack:                                                                                                                    
[firefox #01]     Error: Failed expectation
```

The chrome tests pass and the other (10) firefox tests pass ok and bring up the firefox browser and use the browser ok but they don't try to submit the form as this one does.

Note: I tried adding `--safe-mode` and `--headless` but they didn't help.

I tried surrounding calls with `browser.sleep(2000)`s but that didn't help.

I tried using

```
input.sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
browser.sleep(1000).then(function() {
  $$('input[value="Google Search"].first').click();
});
browser.sleep(2000).then(function() {     
expect($('body').getText()).toContain('123');
});
```

but that didn't help

Comment: You can try with https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-hotkeys

Comment: Can you share the HTML code snippet as well?